# Prove $f$ is integrable on $[-1,1].$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis

Let $f : R \to R$ be defined by $\frac x{|x|}$ if $x \neq 0$ and $0$ if $x = 0$. Prove that f is integrable over the interval $[−1, 1]$ and compute that integral.

Here is what I have so far:

Let $\epsilon > 0$. Let $P = \{-1, -c, c, 1\}$ on $[-1,1]$ with $c, -c$ being $\pm\epsilon$. Then $m_1(f) = -1 = M_1(f)$ and $m_2(f) = 1 = M_2(f)$. Then, ......

I'm not sure how to get $U(P,f) - L(P,f) \le \epsilon$.

Thank you in advance for the help!

Comment: The function $g(x) = |x|$ will produce $f(x) = g'(x)$ (obviously except for at $x = 0$ where $g'(x)$ doesn't exist).  Thus it can certainly be argued that $\left.\int_{-b}^{-\epsilon} f(x) = g(x)\right|_{-\epsilon}^{-b}$ and $\left.\int_{\epsilon}^{b} f(x) = g(x)\right|_{b}^{\epsilon}$ both exist where $b \geq \epsilon > 0$.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $$\int_{-1}^{1}\frac{x}{|x|}dx=\int_{-1}^0-1dx+\int_{0}^11dx.$$

Can you proceed from here?

Comment: I think so,

This is what I have:

$$L(P,f) = \sum_{i=-1}^{-c} m_1(f)(x_i-x_{i-1})+\sum_{i=c}^1m_2(f)(x_i-x_{i-1})=-(c+1)+(1-c)=-2c$$

Does this look right for the lower sum?